Alternatives to partitioning by an ENUM column in MariaDB
For performance reasons, I would like to partition a table that I have based on an enum field. This table is expected to have a very large amount of data, and partitioning on this enum column makes a lot of sense from an application standpoint.
Here is a minimal example for what I am trying to do:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_performance_data;
CREATE TABLE test_performance_data
(
    id            INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    resource_type ENUM ('campaign', 'ad_group', 'ad_item', 'keyword')
)
    PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (resource_type) (
        PARTITION campaigns VALUES IN ('campaign'),
        PARTITION ad_groups VALUES IN ('ad_group'),
        PARTITION ad_items VALUES IN ('ad_item'),
        PARTITION keywords VALUES IN ('keyword')
        );

This unfortunately does not work because from what I understand MariaDB doesn't support partitioning on an enum field. I am getting this error:

Field 'resource_type' is of a not allowed type for this type of partitioning

I tried adding an integer stored generated column partition_id, but that doesn't work either because as per my understanding MariaDB doesn't support partitioning by generated columns either. This is what I tried:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_performance_data;

CREATE TABLE test_performance_data
(
    id            INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    resource_type ENUM ('campaign', 'ad_group', 'ad_item', 'keyword'),
    partition_id  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        CASE 
            WHEN resource_type = 'campaign' THEN 1
            WHEN resource_type = 'ad_group' THEN 2
            WHEN resource_type = 'ad_item' THEN 3
            WHEN resource_type = 'keyword' THEN 4
        END
    ) STORED
)
PARTITION BY LIST (partition_id) (
    PARTITION campaigns VALUES IN (1),
    PARTITION ad_groups VALUES IN (2),
    PARTITION ad_items VALUES IN (3),
    PARTITION keywords VALUES IN (4)
);

And this is the error I got:

Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed

I would really like to keep the partitioning on the database level, meaning that if I need to add a column, it would be managed by the database, not by the application.
I thought about adding an integer partition_id column, and a before insert and before update triggers that update it according to the enum field, but I am not sure that's a good idea because of the performance overhead of the triggers.
What's the best way to go over this?
PS: not sure if relevant, but for context, resource_type (alongside a resource_id column) is used to model a polymorphic relationship in laravel.
I am using version 10.6.18-MariaDB-log of MariaDB.
Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

"a very large amount" - probably not relevant to this question, but don't say things like this.  tell us how much.  very large to some people is thousands of rows, to others it is hundreds of millions.

You may use partition_id  INT AS (resource_type + 0) VIRTUAL - this is allowed, but you'd receive Error 1503. And you cannot solve this error because the generated column cannot be a part of the primary key.

@ysth hard to tell exactly. We have a similar table in our DB that handles performance data for another provider, and it is so large that I can't run select count(*) on it. From INFORMATION_SCHEMA it says about 400 Million rows.
Besides partitioning we will also implement an archiving strategy, but I expect the number of rows to still remain very large.

@Akina I think that's very useful, thank you. If I make id not a primary key, just a normal key, with auto increment, I suppose I am only losing the uniqueness check, right?
Can you check this please: https://dbfiddle.uk/Cj9V899C
How bad is that?

@jarlh in MariaDB I believe the KEY keyword only creates an index but doesn't really enforce uniqueness. In my fiddle you can try inserting rows with the same id, it will work. I understand the confusion however.

@Zakaria, I see. Pretty odd.

you can have it unique per resource type, ALTER TABLE test_performance_data     ADD UNIQUE KEY (id, partition_id);

with so many records, you likely want a bigint id.  Rick James has a lot of experience, do pay attention to what he says.  my first instinct would be 4 separate tables.

Yeah, 4 tables, especially if they have different sets of columns.  (The table names sound like they don't really belong together!)

The tables are indeed different. It's a hierarchy: A keyword belongs to one ad group which belongs to one campaign. The performance data is however exactly the same for all entities. I can have tables like keyword_performance_data and campaign_performance_data ... but they will all have the same columns, that's why a polymorphic relationship made sense to me.

@Zakaria - Generally, a "hierarchical" table does not work well.

ENUM is a red herring.  PARTITION BY LIST rarely helps with performance.  It is better to have composite index(es) starting with the ENUM (or other datatype).  Depending on the various queries, it may eve be beneficial to arrange for the PK to be composite, too.
For further discussion, please provide the queries you expected partitioning to help with, other important queries, and the rest of the CREATE TABLE.  (I can then suggest a set of indexes help the queries.  It may involve suggesting a change to the PRIMARY KEY.)

For the queries, it will be something like fetching all the user's campaign with the performance data for each campaign for the last X days, or fetching all the ad groups for every campaign the user have, and all ad group will be fetched with its performance data.
The thing is, if I am querying from performance_data, I will for sure know the value of the enum field. I do not see any use case where I'd want performance data for a campaign and for an ad group mixed together.

Also expecting many different queries for charts, but still never mixing performance data for different entities.

@Zakaria - Sketch out the CREATE TABLE for the single partitioned table, plus the SELECTs for the things you will fetch.  Repeat the exercise for having 4 separate tables.  I think the 4-table approach will expose that the 4 tables will have different columns.
